# RIGHT ARROW not appearing in the PDF file produced using JasperReports

Tags: pdf

I have this text field that has right arrow included in the text field that I have set but the text appearing in the resulting PDF file has no right arrow with it.

```
<textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle" markup="html">
      <font fontName="Calibri" size="8" isBold="true"/>
</textElement>
<textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{generalManager} + " \u2192 " + $F{manager} + " \u2192 " + $F{teamLeader} + " - EE Count: " + $F{totalEmployeeCount}]]></textFieldExpression>
```

Note: When I change the font to DejavuSans, the right arrow appears.

Is there any work around for Calibri? I have also searched that Calibri, along with DejavuSans, supports right arrow, what could be the problem here?

Comment: If you use Calibri in the report definition, is Calibri used in the final PDF? JasperReports requires special care in case of PDF export.